# Obj-C - Execute animation if filtered result contains > x?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm filtering an NSDictionary, and the filtered items are displayed in a tableView. I want to execute an animation (self.tableView.frame...) ONLY if the filtered count is more than - however, I can't get my filtered count to write an if statement inside of animateTextView. See code below - what is the best way for me to do this?

**.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableDictionary *viewParams = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [viewParams setValue:@"chat" forKey:@"view_name"];
    [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        self.messages = (NSMutableArray *)responseObject;

        [self.tableView reloadData];


            });

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];

}
    - (void) animateTextView:(BOOL) up
    {      

        const int movementDistance = self.keyboardHeight;

        const float movementDuration = 0.2f;
        int movement= movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);


        [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];

        self.upView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.upView.frame, 0, movement);
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(afterAnimationStops)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        self.tableView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.tableView.frame, 0, movement);
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(afterAnimationStops)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];


    }

    - (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {

        if ([self.messageDataFriends count] > 0) {

            NSDictionary *userDictInfo = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"diosSession"]];

            DIOSSession *session = [DIOSSession sharedSession];
            [session setUser:userDictInfo];

            [session user];

            NSString *targetedUser = [self.messageDataFriends objectForKey:@"uid2"];

            NSString *myID = [session user][@"user"][@"uid"];


            NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid contains[cd] %@", targetedUser];

            NSPredicate *p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"targetuser contains[cd] %@", myID];

            NSPredicate *p3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid contains[cd] %@", myID];

            NSPredicate *p4 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"targetuser contains[cd] %@", targetedUser];

            NSCompoundPredicate *pIntermediary1 = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p1, p2,]];

            NSCompoundPredicate * pIntermediary2 = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p3, p4,]];

            NSCompoundPredicate *pFinal = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[pIntermediary1, pIntermediary2]];

            NSArray *filtered = [self.messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pFinal];

            return [filtered count];

            }
```

Comment: At what point do you want your animation to occur? Before or after the new data appears in the table?

Comment: @executor21 After

Answer (score 0):

First, it's probably a good idea to separate the filtering process (a function of the Model part of MVC) from the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method (the Controller sending data to the view):

```
-(NSArray *)filterMessages {
    //returns the filtered array
}
```

You can then save the filtered array in another instance variable, and use that:

```
- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return self.filteredMessages.count;
}
```

Finally, to animate when needed:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.messages = (NSMutableArray *)responseObject;
    self.filteredMessages = [self filterMessages];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    if(self.filteredMessages.count > ANIMATE_THRESHHOLD){
        [self animateTextView:YES];
    }

});
```

By the way, unless you are making UI calls to do it, the filtering can be pulled off the main thread. Simply move the call to `filterMessages` and the cast before it outside the dispatch block.